# Error when testing Service Provider implemented using SimpleSAML

Tags: php, single-sign-on, saml, adfs, simplesamlphp

[![I have setup the service provider for our PHP application using Simple SAML. I followed the steps on  https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-sp to setup the service provider, but I am receiving an error when attempting to test the SP as per the documentation. The error message just says 'An error has occurred'. I installed SAMLTracer extension and was able to view the response, but could not gather much info.
I am attaching the screenshot here.
I am a newbie in this.. Could someone please guide me in the right direction ? Any help would be highly appreciated.

[image: Error on entering credentials]

Comment: Could you paste the SAML output so we can parse the SAML response?